# Bluetooth 5.0 adapter help

Tags: drivers, 20.04, usb, bluetooth

I just changed my 4.0 adapter for the new Bluetooth 5.0 adapter, but found out it doesn't work on Ubuntu. Can someone please help me and tell what steps exactly I need to follow to be able to make it work?

1. `lsusb` output:
   `Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:8771 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio`
2. `hciconfig -a`:

```
    BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:21 acl:0 sco:0 events:2 errors:0
    TX bytes:6 acl:0 sco:0 commands:2 errors:0
    Features: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
    Packet type: DM1 DH1 HV1 
    Link policy: 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT
```

3. `hcitool dev` is empty
4. `bluetoothctl --version` is `bluetoothctl: 5.53`
5. `rfkill` is:

```
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 1 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked
```

6. `btmon` is:

```
Failed to bind channel: Operation not permitted
```

What commands outputs else you want me to show here? Adapter is `DEXP AT-BT501`, chipset is `RTL8761B`. Ubuntu is 20.04 LTS.

UPD: Ubuntu mainline says my kernel is `5.13.0-37`, the device is working, because it has no problem on Windows.

UPD2: Logs say `Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: firmware file rtl_bt/rtl8761b_fw.bin not found`

Comment: Which kernel is currently running on your machine? That device should be picked up with kernels 5.8 and newer 

Comment: @matigo, Ubuntu mainline says it's 5.13.0-37, the device is working, because it has no prolem on Windows

Comment: Do you see anything in `/var/log/syslog` for the device?

Comment: @matigo, I didn't check it, how do you do that and what exactly to do?

Comment: You can use the "Logs" application to view logs or, if you prefer the command line, something like `sudo nano /var/log/syslog` will let you access the system log. From there you can search for details regarding your adapter.

Comment: @matigo, it says "Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: firmware file rtl_bt/rtl8761b_fw.bin not found"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The binary for the RTL8761b is not currently part of the Linux kernel but, according to [this Ubuntu Forums post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2453631&p=14062516#post14062516), you can obtain it from a GitHub repository.

Here's how:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Change to the temporary directory:

   ```
   cd /tmp
   ```
2. Download the configuration and firmware files [from GitHub](https://github.com/Realtek-OpenSource/android_hardware_realtek):

   ```
   wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Realtek-OpenSource/android_hardware_realtek/rtk1395/bt/rtkbt/Firmware/BT/rtl8761b_config
   wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Realtek-OpenSource/android_hardware_realtek/rtk1395/bt/rtkbt/Firmware/BT/rtl8761b_fw
   ```
3. Move the appropriate files to your `/lib/firmware/rtl_bt` directory:

   ```
   sudo mv rtl8761b_config /lib/firmware/rtl_bt/rtl8761b_config.bin
   sudo mv rtl8761b_fw /lib/firmware/rtl_bt/rtl8761b_fw.bin
   ```
4. Run `modprobe`:

   ```
   sudo modprobe btusb
   ```
5. Restart the Bluetooth service:

   ```
   sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service
   ```

If everything is good, Bluetooth will now be operational. Running `hciconfig -a` will confirm whether the system can use the radio or not.

Comment: Thanks, it helped, but you forgot to add ```.bin``` in the line ```sudo mv rtl8761b_fw /lib/firmware/rtl_bt/rtl8761b_fw```, without it it doesn't work

Comment: @Arzybek good catch. Thanks for letting me know. I've updated the answer so that other people won't have an issue in the future 

Answer (score 2):

For some reason Linux kernel 5.15 is now looking for rtl8761bu_fw.bin and rtl8761bu_config.bin

Linux kernel 5.13 was happy with rtl8761b_fw.bin and rtl8761b_config.bin

I just "sudo cp rtl8761b_fw.bin rtl8761bu_fw.bin"

Comment: Same for kernel 5.19 : Without bu, I get BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00 (DOWN). After renaming rtl8761b in rtl8761bu, I got BD Address: 7C:10:C9:67:E4:05 (UP RUNNING)

Answer (score 1):

I've updated the kernel to version 6.5 and it suddenly it worked. But the connection was failing every time. so i just had to install `libspa-0.2-bluetooth`. Try to do the following:

1. Update your kernel to a more updated version, I recommend 6.5 or above.
2. Install `libspa-0.2-bluetooth` with

   ```
   sudo apt install libspa-0.2-bluetooth
   ```
3. Reboot

   ```
   reboot
   ```